# fragment recyclerview dissapear after navigating up kotlin java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is the basic configuration of an App Im developing. This App has two fragments `FirstFragment` and `SecondFragment` contained in a `<FrameLayout` in `MainActivity`.
`SecondFragment` must always shows a recyclerview with items

**PROBLEM**

the first time I click on `go to Second Fragment` button (within First Fragment), it does goes and shows the recyclerview in second fragment.

the problem is that anytime I return (navigate up) and click the button again... the recyclerview doesnt appear anymore in the second fragment.

In a more advanced version of this example, I need to enter from another activity to MainActivity, or change the orientation of the cellphone, to be able again to display the recyclerview with items, in the second fragment when clickin on the button...

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**firts_fragment.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonToSF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Go to Second Fragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**second_fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvItemsList"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**item.xml**

```
   <CardView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvWord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Word" />
  </CardView>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val firstFragment = FirstFragment()
    private val firstFragmentTAG_NAME = "FIRST_FRAGMENT_TAG"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //go to first fragment by default
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment, firstFragmentTAG_NAME)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    fun callRvAdapter(context: Context) {
        val arrayItems = ArrayList<MyModel>()

        arrayItems.add(MyModel("Verbs"))
        arrayItems.add(MyModel("Nouns"))
        arrayItems.add(MyModel("Adverbs"))

        rvItemsList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        rvItemsList.adapter = MyAdapter(arrayItems, context)
    }

    fun getToSecondFragment() {
        val secondFragment = SecondFragment()
        val secondFragmentTAGNAME = "SECOND_FRAGMENT_TAG"

        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment, secondFragmentTAGNAME)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment.kt**

```
class FirstFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        buttonToSF.setOnClickListener{
            (activity as MainActivity).getToSecondFragment()
        }
    }
}
```

**SecondFragment.kt**

```
class SecondFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?{
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false)

        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        (activity as MainActivity).callRvAdapter(requireContext())
    }
}
```

**MyModel.kt**

```
 class MyModel(val hm_title:String)
```

**MyAdapter**

```
class MyAdapter(val arrayList: ArrayList<MyModel>, val context: Context) :
     RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        fun bindItems(model: MyModel){
            itemView.tvWord.text = model.hm_title
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(arrayList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }
}
```

this is what I have so far... I need the function `callRvAdapter()` remains always in `MainActivity` and this function always be called from within second fragment.

**What am doing wrong?**

Comment: can you move `(activity as MainActivity).callRvAdapter(requireContext())` to `onCreateView`

Comment: did you test it? it doesnt  work

Comment: If you change cellphone orientation and then items appear that means you could lost the fragment state. You need to save the list items onSaveInstanceState() and try to fetch them onActivityCreated()